# Fractional pixel size with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, graphics

I want to display zoomed images with text and graphics annotations for each pixel. Here is a sample program to annotate each pixel of grayscale image with its value:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int scale = 44;

    QApplication   a(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    QGraphicsView  view(&scene);
    QImage         image("test.bmp");

    scene.addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image.scaled(scale*image.width(), scale*image.height())));

    for (int x = 0; x < image.width(); ++x)
      for (int y = 0; y < image.height(); ++y) {
        auto text = new QGraphicsSimpleTextItem();

        text->setText(QString::number(qGray(image.pixel(x, y))));
        text->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::red));
        text->setPos(scale*(x+0.2), scale*(y+0.2));
        scene.addItem(text);
      }

    view.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

It rescales image pixels to `scale`x`scale` squares and requires corresponding rescale of coordinates for annotations. I would like to retain 1x1 pixel size and use this coordinate system for annotations: `text->setPos(x+0.2, y+0.2)` would replace corresponding line above. Can it be done with `QGraphicsScene`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QGraphicsView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html) has its own scale, use that instead of rescaling the image yourself. If you scale the image before adding it to the scene, the pixel positions and number of pixels are of course altered. The easier way is to use QGraphicsView scale and keep the original image size and pixel positions. The position you use for the QGraphicsItem is also the same position in the image.

For the text, you can set a flag:

```
text->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations,true);
```

to let it stay the same size no matter how much you zoom in.

This should work:

```
const int scale = 44;

QApplication   a(argc, argv);
QGraphicsScene scene;
QGraphicsView  view(&scene);
QImage         image("test.bmp");

scene.addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));

for (int x = 0; x < image.width(); ++x) {
    for (int y = 0; y < image.height(); ++y) {
        QGraphicsSimpleTextItem* text = new QGraphicsSimpleTextItem();

        text->setText(QString::number(qGray(image.pixel(x, y))));
        text->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::red));
        text->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations,true);
        text->setPos(x+0.2, y+0.2);
        scene.addItem(text);
    }
}
view.scale(scale, scale);
view.show();

return a.exec();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried it (see gist.github.com/2b6ba7987e80987591e5.git) and the numbers are not displayed.

Comment: I edited the answer and you already used the right scale method. Remove the mapFrom/ToScene and use the coordinates itself (these are the pixel coordinates of your image, if you do not scale the image before adding it to the scene).

Comment: Thank you. It works nicely for text annotations. I tried the same approach with `QGraphicsLineItem` for graphic annotations, but either the line length or its width is wrong depending on `ItemIgnoresTransformations` setting (see [edited snippet](http://codeshare.io/d6vMM)).

Comment: I see. Yeah, the behavior is somehow not intuitiv. Maybe, that's because internally, the line has a position and a length. The position is right, but length is not. And if my answer solved your original problem, it would be nice, if you mark it as solved :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89267/discussion-between-gombat-and-paul-jurczak).